# Is there a way to click and drag, bulk direct select in the shape of a circle in Illustrator?

Tags: adobe-illustrator

When you have the Direct Select tool, you can click and drag. This bulk selects in the shape of a square, selecting anything within that shape. Is there a way to do this so that the shape it selects is a circle?

Comment: Hi, and welcome to gd.se! You'll get a much more useful answer if you describe what problem you're trying to solve, because the very short answer to what you've asked is "No," which isn't useful at all.

Comment: You may also find it easier to select things using the layers palette; command/control click on the layers to select multiple layers.

Answer (score 0):

Use the **Lasso Tool** if you want a circular selection. No, you can't make circular selections with the Direct Selection Tool.

But be aware, Illustrator selects anything a selection touches. If you touch a rectangle with a circular selection, then rectangle is selected.